# How can I set up netbeans to push to a password protected mercurial repository?

Tags: version-control, netbeans, mercurial

I have decided to use Netbeans and Mercurial for my latest project (after no end of headaches with Visual Studio). My Mercurial repository is set up and I can do anything like with it, from the command line.

Specifically, I can push and pull my code all day long by using an ssh:// login on the command line. However, when I use Netbeans Share->Push option, it simply hangs because it doesn't have my password.

How can I configure it to either prompt me for a password, store my password, or use an SSH key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna use ssh, see [this faq](http://bitbucket.org/help/UsingSSH).

For http/https, you may add to .hg/hgrc following lines:

```
[paths]
default = https://username:password@some.url/repo
```

Comment: The upcoming Mercurial 1.3 has a nice way of configuring HTTP auth in a central place: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth This avoids the problem of having to spread around the password in many different .hg/hgrc files.

Answer (score 0):

In your mercurial config :

```
ssh = C:\path\plink -l user -pw password
```